# cellForRowAtIndexPath is called but without stacktrace

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode8, stack-trace

Using Swift 3, the UITableView's `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: @autoclosure @escaping IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` is being called. I want to track who's calling this function. As far as I know, this will only be called if there's a need for a cell to display. However, in stacktrace `override internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: @autoclosure @escaping Int) -> Int` is not called and there is no stacktrace. Could someone advice to where to start digging up? Thanks!

See attached screenshot
[image: No Stacktrace]

Comment: Why don't you think `numberOfSections` (or do you mean `numberOfRowsInSection`) isn't being called?

Comment: I put a breakpoint in `numberOfRowsInSection` but it is never been called

Comment: Are you sure it has the correct signature? Update your question with relevant code.

Comment: Yes it is the cellForRowAt function of UITableView, I just copied its Interface declaration. Here is the actual function declaratoin name `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

Comment: I was asking about `numberOfRowsInSection` since that is the one you are asking about.

Comment: I have now updated the complete func name of numberOfRowsInSection of UITableView in my question mate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134734/discussion-between-chlkdst-and-rmaddy).

Comment: What is the exact question now? Do you want to know **who** calls `cellForRowAt:indexPath` and why you don't see the stacktrace -- or do you want to know why it's not called (and in this case, your breakpoint won't get hit and you won't stop in the debugger)?

Comment: Hi mate @AndreasOetjen, yes! I want to know *who* calls `cellForRowAt:indexPath` and I can't seem to see the full stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

By default, you only see the stack trace that contains debug symbols. So you won't see many framework internals here.

To see *everything*, there is a small button at the bottom of the stack trace window, third position from the right, that will enable also methods without debug symbols:

[image: Enable/Disable full stack trace]

(In fact, it depends on your Xcode version; in older versions there is some sort of slider which will display more or less details in the stack trace).

Comment: I ticked that option in Debug navigator, please see updated stacktrace. Still no luck. numberOfRowInSection is not even in the stacktrace

Comment: Surely it is not. `numberOfRows:inSection` will be called by the table view _before_ `cellForRow:atIndexPath`, so it's definetly not supposed to be in the stacktrace.

Comment: Yup I get it now, it's always the case the `numberOfRows:inSection` is in the stacktrace. My main problem is I do not know who triggers the `cellForRow:atIndexPath`

Comment: It's triggered by the `UITableView`. Once the table is displayed, it realizes that it has to display cells, and then calls this method at its `UITableViewDataSource`, which in your case is your `TOCViewController` (and it only calls this method for cells to be displayed, not for all data in the table)

Answer (score 0):

As @AndreasOetjen mentioned, this is a normal behavior because the method get's called from a UIKit Framework class. The call-stack in this Framework is hidden by default and can be opt-io by the mentioned buttons.